# DDD in a modular monolith. How Consistency is Maintained?

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design

I have three bounded contexts:

1. commercial
2. inventory
3. financial departments

Each has its proper domain layers, application layers, DB and etc.
When commercial department sells or orders something, the inventory departments needs to increase or decrease the value of the amount of product present in inventory and financial department needs to pay or receive money from the transaction.

I read that, in ***micro-services***, I should use event driven like *kafka*. **But in a *modular monolith* how should I do it?**

My first thought was to make one http request for each department, but if one fails the DB consistency will be lost.
If I was supposed to do it in code, where should I put it? (Should be like unit of work or something?) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> in a modular monolith how should I do it?

The usual answer is "messaging".

Modules make decisions on their own, using their own local copies of information.  A module is the authority for its own decisions ("the answer is now 7!"), but relies on copies of information from the outside ("I don't what the answer is now, but I received a note that says 5 minutes ago the answer was 7").

> When commercial department sells or orders something, the inventory departments needs to increase or decrease the value of the amount of product present in inventory and financial department needs to pay or receive money from the transaction.

Yes, but those needs aren't usually immediate.  It's much more common to have a (possibly implicit) service level: to five nines, we expect information to be copied between modules in 1 millisecond, or whatever.

(This is especially true if you are dealing in a domain with physical inventory, because there is often some latency when trying to bring the digital model of the warehouse into alignment with the physical warehouse).

Recommend reading: Pat Helland

- [Data on the Outside vs Data on the Inside](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf) (2005)
- [Memories, Guesses and Apologies](https://web.archive.org/web/20100722052618/https://blogs.msdn.com/b/pathelland/archive/2007/05/15/memories-guesses-and-apologies.aspx) (2007)
- [Immutability Changes Everything](https://web.archive.org/web/20150128015154/http://www.cidrdb.org/cidr2015/Papers/CIDR15_Paper16.pdf) (2015)

---

If you have reliable message transport between the modules, then communication is relatively easy.  I make a decision, I send a copy of the decision to you, you make a decision.

> My first thought was to make one http request for each department, but if one fails the DB consistency will be lost.

When you don't have reliable message transport between modules, life gets more complicated.  One common approach is to use pull, rather than push.  You ask me for a batch of messages starting from the last message you received, and I fill you in on those details; when you have copied those messages locally, you can then ask for another batch.

That, plus a little bit of extra bookkeeping to make sure that you don't process a duplicate message twice if that's going to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In a modular monolith, you should treat your modules(bounded contexts) as if they are independently deployable units. Ideally with no dependency between modules. You should be able at any point to easily split it into microservices if you need to.
When it comes to events, yes relying on eventual consistency is a good idea, and using integration events makes sense in your case. However, using Kafka to exchanges messages between two modules that are in the same repository and running in the same machine is a bit of overhead. What I suggest is to create an events bus interface that both modules will implement. The implementation can be an in-memory event bus.
If at one point you need to split the monolith and deploy a module separately (ex: for scalability reasons ) you can just switch the implementation from in-memory to something like Kafka.
A similar implementation of the modular monolith is done in this repo: https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd

Answer (score 0):

In general your choices in a monolith are the same as in microservices:

- You can choose a more eventually consistent approach and use domain events to trigger changes in other bounded contexts.
- You can use a saga, which will also be eventually consistent (because aggregates define your consistency boundaries and don't cross bounded contexts, there will be observable windows of time where one bounded context has updated to reflect new information while another one hasn't), but because the process of updating is now a trackable entity in your model, you can take appropriate actions.

For instance, a "making a sale" saga might entail (assuming that the commercial department has finalized which items are to be sold):

- Reserving the items to be sold with the inventory service, to prevent an item from being sold twice (note that it's probably a good idea to ask the business experts whether it's preferred to occasionally make a sale when there's no inventory or to simply refuse to make sales if there's a chance that the inventory might not be there... depending on what you're selling, the answer could go either way)
- Once the inventory has been reserved, arrange with the financial department to collect payment
- Once payment has been collected (for whatever that means), have the inventory service (NB: inventory service is probably not a good name... something like warehouse or fulfillment might be a better match to the domain language) remove the items from inventory

At each of these steps, you might occasionally have a failure, and you'll need to decide whether to wait and retry or to declare the entire operation a failure and rollback the earlier steps (e.g. if the inventory service can't fulfill the order (maybe someone in the warehouse absconded with the merchandise without having the common decency to adjust the inventory on their way out with the loot), you'll have to have the financial department cancel/refund the bill and unreserve the inventory... or maybe you treat that as such an exceptional condition that you signal a human to come up with a solution that works), and given enough failures there's a point where the saga will signal someone to manually resolve things.

The saga will itself be an entity/aggregate in your domain, with it's own durable state.